# Storage Object Viewer role not able to read

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I have a Service Account which I have given Storage Object Viewer role on a Google Storage Bucket

[image]

Now, I have given this Service Account to a Cloud Function for reading objects from the bucket. But I get the following exception in Cloud Function when the service account has Storage Object Viewer role:

> googleapi: Error 403:
>   service-account-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have
>   storage.buckets.get access to my-bucket., forbidden

When I give the role of Storage Admin to the Service Account, the Cloud Function is able to read from the Bucket.

But it fails when Storage Object Viewer role is given. Why could this be happening?

`gsutil defacl get gs://my-bucket` gives following output:

```
[
  {
    "entity": "project-owners-1111111111111",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "1111111111111",
      "team": "owners"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-editors-1111111111111",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "1111111111111",
      "team": "editors"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-viewers-1111111111111",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "1111111111111",
      "team": "viewers"
    },
    "role": "READER"
  }
]
```

`gsutil iam get gs://my-bucket` outputs:

```
{
  "members": [
    "serviceAccount:cf-access@project-id-793.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  ],
  "role": "roles/storage.objectViewer"
}
```

But `gsutil iam get gs://my-bucket/my-object` does not have cf-access@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com as the member.

Why could this be happening?

The cloud function Go code causing the error is:

```
func (g *GoogleBucket) Initialize(bucket string, folder string) error {

    g.client = nil
    g.bucket = nil

    g.bucketName = bucket
    g.custFolder = folder

    var err error
    g.ctx = context.Background()

    g.client, err = storage.NewClient(g.ctx)
    g.bucket = g.client.Bucket(g.bucketName)

    _, err = g.bucket.Attrs(g.ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to create Google Bucket client: " + err.Error())
        g.bucket = nil
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("Bucket initialized correctly")
    return nil
}
```

Comment: If a Cloud Storage Bucket is made `private` by the command `gsutil defacl set private gs://mybucket` only Project Owners, Project Editors, and Bucket IAM members will be able to access the bucket. Check with this command `gsutil defacl get gs://mybucket`. If the command reports an error, the bucket is private. You will then need to add access thru the `gsutil iam ch ...` command.

Comment: The command `gsutil defacl get gs://mybucket` did not return any error, and it showed  the json output with all roles

Comment: And the roles are ...... Edit your question with the details.

Comment: Are the Project IDs the same for the service account and Bucket? Check the bucket IAM permissions for the exact object that you are trying to access. Edit your question with details.

Comment: `gsutil iam get gs://mybucket/myobject`

Comment: The project IDs are same. I've updated the question with `gsutil iam get gs://my-bucket` output

Comment: I need the Object ACL not the Bucket ACL.

Comment: I've updated the question with Object ACL. The service account is not member of object ACL. Why could this be?

Comment: I don't know. There is something missing in the details that you are providing or in the history of this bucket/project. The answer is in the details. I cannot see them from here.

Comment: One item that I just realized. The role `roles/storage.ojbectViewer` does not have the permissions `storage.buckets.get`. What API are you trying to use that is generating this error? To access an object your need `storage.objects.get`. Notice the difference? Include the code that is actually causing this error message.

Comment: I've added the code. Also, `roles/storage.ojbectViewer` should have `storage.buckets.get` as per https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles , isn't it?

Comment: That is in the role `roles/storage.legacyBucketReader`.

Comment: When posting code and an error message, post what line of code generated the error. For your code include the package that you are using. I will assume that your error is at this line `g.bucket.Attrs(g.ctx)`. You do NOT have permission to get bucket attributes. You have permission to read an object. If you want to get the bucket attributes add the role `roles/storage.legacyBucketReader`